# Typing d in insert mode briefly moves cursor backwards

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, insert-mode, normal-mode

In Vim, when I'm in `Insert` mode and hit `d`, the cursor moves back one spot for a second, then jumps back to behind the letter just typed. This is quite distracting when typing texts.

It looks like Vim is expecting a command because unlike other keystrokes, the `d` appears in the bottom right corner of the screen for a second.

However, according to `:help` the `d` only triggers an action in `Normal` mode, where it means delete. Would anyone know what `d` does in `Insert` mode and whether it's possible to avoid this behavior, e.g. through remapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got an insert mode mapping that begins with a `d`, and Vim is waiting to see if you're typing that mapping or something else. To see what the mapping is, and where it was set, try the command:

```
:verbose imap d
```

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, I get to see mappings that don't have a d in them at all: `i  deoplete#auto_complete([]) * : "<C-Y>"`
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 51
`i  deoplete#close_popup() * : "<Tab>"<Space>`
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 48

Comment: @TimothyRoes Those mappings _do_ have a `d` in them! They are mappings for `deoplete#...` i.e. when you type `deoplete#...`, the bit after the `*` will be entered instead. You should take a look at lines 48 and 51 of your `.vimrc`, because it looks as though the mappings there are broken/missing their `lhs` (i.e. their triggers).

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it. The syntax was wrong.  Deoplete `:help` was rather terse on this point, but referring to the general vim `:help`I managed to understand `:map-expr` .